# Visual Studio Intellisense help for keywords

Tags: c#, intellisense

Is it possible to add intellisense help to keywords of the c# language? There are lots of keywords that could use an explanation and might also help beginners get a better insight.

Comment: Have you looked into the Dynamic Help of Visual Studio? http://helpware.net/mshelp2/demo/DynamicHelp.htm

Comment: This is more about putting the information at ones finger tips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please see below link, it may help you:

[Advanced Basics IntelliSense Code Snippets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188694.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can find a list of the C# keywords **[here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb(VS.71).aspx)** - this may help. I'm not entirely certain whether there is a way of inputting this into IntelliSense, but MSDN offers a large amount of information regarding these keywords.